Disable other checkboxes with specific word when one checkbox with same is checked
I have using following code to create dynamic checkbox fields.... and storing batch unique ids as comma separated values in database for specific user...
<?php
// Fetching values from mysql database table
foreach ($result as $data){
 $batch_uid = $data['batch_uid'];
 $batch_day = $data['batch_day'];
 $batch_start_time = $data['batch_start_time'];
 $batch_end_time = $data['batch_end_time'];
?>

 <input id="batches_alloted<?php echo $batch_uid;?>" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $batch_uid;?>">&nbsp; <label id="batches_alloted_label<?php echo $batch_uid;?>" for="batches_alloted<?php echo $batch_uid;?>"> <?php echo $batch_day." ".date("H:i", strtotime($batch_start_time))." - ".date("H:i", strtotime($batch_end_time));?> </label>

<?php } ?>

With this code, I am getting checkboxes as follows :
<input id="batches_allotedQOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142" for="batches_allotedQOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142">Monday 15:00 - 16:00</label>                    
<input id="batches_allotedWPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="WPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelWPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945" for="batches_allotedWPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945">Monday 16:00 - 17:00</label>                    
<input id="batches_allotedLHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="LHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelLHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145" for="batches_allotedLHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145">Monday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedPSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="PSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelPSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733" for="batches_allotedPSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733">Tuesday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedWFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="WFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelWFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629" for="batches_allotedWFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629">Tuesday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedQYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175" for="batches_allotedQYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175">Tuesday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedYTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="YTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelYTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231" for="batches_allotedYTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231">Wednesday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedFUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="FUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelFUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333" for="batches_allotedFUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333">Wednesday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="ZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818" for="batches_allotedZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818">Wednesday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedOWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="OWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelOWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326" for="batches_allotedOWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326">Thursday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedMOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="MOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelMOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344" for="batches_allotedMOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344">Thursday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedQLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154" for="batches_allotedQLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154">Thursday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedGNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="GNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelGNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598" for="batches_allotedGNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598">Friday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedCVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="CVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelCVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287" for="batches_allotedCVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287">Friday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedDODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="DODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelDODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664" for="batches_allotedDODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664">Friday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedQGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919" for="batches_allotedQGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919">Saturday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedBLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="BLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelBLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354" for="batches_allotedBLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354">Saturday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
<input id="batches_allotedWGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="WGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelWGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465" for="batches_allotedWGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465">Saturday 17:00 - 18:00</label>          
                                                    

MY GOAL :
If one checkbox with label containing word Monday is checked, other checkboxes containing word Monday in label should be disabled. and same for other all days..
I tried javascript to disable other checkboxes when one chekbox is checked. But in that case, all other checkboxes getting disbaled.
I want to allocate Per Day One Batch only. So to avoid accidental checking checkboxes of other batch on same day, I am trying this...

I'd suggest converting the HTML to groups of radio buttons per-day. That way you get this behaviour by default, and it will be less brittle. Also, I'd strongly suggest you remove the dynamic id and for attributes in your HTML. It's ugly and unnecessary. Put the <input /> elements inside the <label> if you're trying to make the hit area bigger.

@RoryMcCrossan I want save multiple checkbox values for one user. Can it be done with radio buttons ?

Yes - as I suggested in the first comment. The complexity will be in updating your server-side code to handle the changes to the way the data will be sent (ie. in multiple values batched by day instead of all as a single array)

@RoryMcCrossan I will try with your suggestion.. and will update here.. thanks

Here's an example of what you want your HTML output to look like: https://jsfiddle.net/c8uwqLdx/

If you really want to use Checkboxes, here is an example.


$(function() {
  function uncheckSiblings(e) {
    var me = $(e.target);
    me.siblings().prop("checked", false);
  }

  $(".single-check").click(uncheckSiblings);
});
.single-check {
  width: 240px;
}

.single-check label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-check">
  <input id="batches_allotedQOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142" for="batches_allotedQOHLPTPJH1907202409472819392142">Monday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedWPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="WPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelWPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945" for="batches_allotedWPPUFIEUM1907202409535139661945">Monday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedLHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="LHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelLHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145" for="batches_allotedLHTUUBIIL1907202411033362282145">Monday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
</div>
<div class="single-check">
  <input id="batches_allotedPSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="PSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelPSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733" for="batches_allotedPSFGMCELV1907202410193019248733">Tuesday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedWFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="WFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelWFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629" for="batches_allotedWFONOMPTZ1907202411082492322629">Tuesday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedQYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175" for="batches_allotedQYTCBTUED1907202411124393971175">Tuesday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
</div>
<div class="single-check">
  <input id="batches_allotedYTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="YTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelYTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231" for="batches_allotedYTBFRKLIQ1907202411242665949231">Wednesday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedFUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="FUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelFUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333" for="batches_allotedFUOTJBSDU1907202411263977236333">Wednesday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="ZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818" for="batches_allotedZKLMJYAWU1907202411265942573818">Wednesday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
</div>
<div class="single-check">
  <input id="batches_allotedOWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="OWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelOWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326" for="batches_allotedOWZNUOBAO1907202411280692299326">Thursday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedMOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="MOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelMOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344" for="batches_allotedMOLZKHPDJ1907202411282689576344">Thursday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedQLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154" for="batches_allotedQLTGLKDIH1907202411284248122154">Thursday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
</div>
<div class="single-check">
  <input id="batches_allotedGNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="GNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelGNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598" for="batches_allotedGNCSRUTKA1907202412050247112598">Friday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedCVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="CVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelCVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287" for="batches_allotedCVWPQAIFK1907202412051523368287">Friday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedDODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="DODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelDODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664" for="batches_allotedDODUBZYFT1907202412053088628664">Friday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
</div>
<div class="single-check">
  <input id="batches_allotedQGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="QGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelQGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919" for="batches_allotedQGSRRAKAA1907202412063285189919">Saturday 15:00 - 16:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedBLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="BLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelBLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354" for="batches_allotedBLEQZPQYE1907202412064592615354">Saturday 16:00 - 17:00</label>
  <input id="batches_allotedWGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="WGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465">&nbsp;<label id="batches_alloted_labelWGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465" for="batches_allotedWGBVZARPR1907202412065757958465">Saturday 17:00 - 18:00</label>
</div>



You will still need to update your PHP to render the correct HTML. Something like this if it is a set number.
<?php
echo "<div class='single-check'>\r\n";
$i = 1;
// Fetching values from mysql database table
foreach ($result as $data){
  $batch_uid = $data['batch_uid'];
  $batch_day = $data['batch_day'];
  $batch_start_time = $data['batch_start_time'];
  $batch_end_time = $data['batch_end_time'];
  $delim = "</div>\r\n<div class='single-click'>\r\n"
?>

 <input id="batches_alloted<?php echo $batch_uid;?>" name="batches_alloted[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $batch_uid;?>">&nbsp; <label id="batches_alloted_label<?php echo $batch_uid;?>" for="batches_alloted<?php echo $batch_uid;?>"> <?php echo $batch_day." ".date("H:i", strtotime($batch_start_time))." - ".date("H:i", strtotime($batch_end_time));?> </label>

<?php 
  if($i++ % 3 == 0){
    echo @delim;
  }
}
echo "</div>\r\n"
?>

